# Users, form and tasks association rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, task, model-associations

I have an app allowing a user to fill a form (named "checklist") and then have a list of tasks he will have to do. The tasks (named "advices") are related to the answers that the user gave in the form. 
For example, if a question is "have you cooked dinner ?" and the user answers "no", then an advice "go cook dinner" will be displayed.

Once a advice is done, the user can mark it as completed. Advices are the same for all users. They already are created in the app by admin.

So users have a checklist, checklist belongs to a user.

**The problem I encounter is : when a user marks an advice as completed, it is marked as completed for all users. That should not be.**

I am not really sure how to fix this. Associations "Has-many", and "Belongs_to" between advices and users should not work since the user does not create the advices ?

I am new to rails so I would be happy if someone could help.
Note that I use Devise to manage users.

**Schema :**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160407143608) do

  create_table "advices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.boolean  "status"
    t.string   "linkname1"
    t.text     "link1"
    t.text     "link2"
    t.string   "linkname2"
    t.text     "link3"
    t.string   "linkname3"
    t.integer  "ref"
    t.boolean  "completed"
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",       null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "checklists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean  "facebook"
    t.boolean  "twitter"
    t.boolean  "linkedin"
    t.boolean  "viadeo"
    t.boolean  "instagram"
    t.boolean  "community"
    t.boolean  "cms"
    t.boolean  "seo"
    t.boolean  "crowdfunding"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "checklists", ["user_id"], name: "index_checklists_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Models :

```
class Advice < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
end

class Checklist < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :checklists
end
```

**View :**

```
<%= advice.name %> | <%= link_to "Completed", complete_advices_path(advice), method: :put %>
```

**controller :**

```
  def complete
   @advice.completed = true
   @advice.save
   redirect_to root_path
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a join model.

`$ rails g model UserAdvice user:references advice:references`

```
class UserAdvice
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :advice
end
```

in user.rb

```
has_many :user_advices
has_many :advices, through: :user_advices
```

in advice.rb

```
has_many :user_advices
has_many :users, through: :user_advices
```

Create a record in the join model when something gets checked off and then query that table to make sure the task is done for an individual user.

So, when a user checks off a task and submits, instead of using the `completed` boolean, you'd actually create a record that has the `advice_id` and the `user_id`. Then if that record exist for that advice, it should be checked off for that user. Does that make sense?

If you were hiding the completed tasks from users who had completed them, for instance, you could say something like

```
<% if UserAdvice.where(user_id: current_user.id, advice_id: advice.id).count > 0 %>
```

This will work, and is fine at first, but doing it this way could slow down your app, though. If there are a lot of advices, what you'd probably want to do is run the query once and get all the `user_advice` records and pluck the ids. Then check against that array of ids against the individual record.

In your controller

```
 # this will return an array of advice_ids
 @user_advices = UserAdvice.where(user_id: current_user).pluck(:advice_id)
```

Then, as you iterate through advices in your view:

```
<% unless @user_advices.include?(advice.id) %>
  show the advice
<% end %>
```

EDIT:

To create the record inside that complete action:

```
def complete
  UserAdvice.create(user_id: current_user.id, advice_id: @advice.id)
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: Thank you toddmetheny for your answer. hmm, I generated the join model and added the new associations in user.rb and advice.rb. But I actually  don't really understand what to do then. Have you an example ?

Comment: @Ryley38 added some edits. I can explain further if I need to.

Comment: I also added some edit. Thank you for these details.
Yes I aimed to display the advice if the completed boolean is "false".
Currently, by clicking a link in the view, the user call the "complete" action which change the value of the boolean. So this action should create the user_advice record instead ? Sorry for the newby question but what's the proper way to create it with the action ?